# charAt no me imprime 0 ni 1

Tags: java

tengo entendido que charAt me toma el valor en la posición que yo le diga, pero resulta que en el string "100110", me imprime los 1 como 49 y los 0 como 48 y yo necesito son los 0 y 1. Muestro una parte de mi codigo:

```
    public void evaluarPalabra() {

    System.out.print("Ingrese palabra a evaluar: ");
    String palabra = entrada.next();
    lg = new ListaGenerica();

    //Hago una lista generica con los digitos de la palabra a evaluar.
    for (int i = 0; i < palabra.length(); i++) {
        lg.insertar(lg.cantidad() + 1, palabra.charAt(i));
        lg.imprimir();
    }
```

Quiero romper la palabra ingresada y colocar cada dígito en una lista generica, pero se agregan solo 48s y 49s. Qué pasa?

"entrada" es objeto de la clase Scanner y la clase imprimir():

```
public void imprimir() {
    Nodo reco = raiz;
    while (reco != null) {
        System.out.print(reco.info);
        reco = reco.sig;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Qué es `entrada` y como imprime el método `ListaGenerica.imprimir()`?

Comment: Acabo de editar respondiéndote al final.

Comment: Pero al parecer tú lo que imprimes es algo relativo a una instancia de `Nodo` aquí: `System.out.print(reco.info);`. ¿Eso que es? ¿Por qué no imprimes el resultado de `palabra.charAt(i)` por ejemplo, en el `for` de arriba para probar?

Comment: 48 es el código Ascii para el número 0, y el 49 es el código Ascii del número 1. Estoy suponiendo que estás guardando mal el caracter que estás leyendo, pero no lo puedo ver porque no estás poniendo los métodos donde guardas los valores leídos.